# Background Image is not showing in Laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to show background image in my Laravel project from css.
But image is not showing. I have checked the image path and it is correct.
I am using **Voyager Admin Panel**. 
I am saving image path from `config/filesystems.php`

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('images'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public/images',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

**html**

```
<div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('public/images/{{ $banner[0]->banner_image }}')">
```

And my image path is `public\images\image_name`.

In console I have found the below error
[image]

Actual path is `public/images/banners/March2019/image_name`

But here shown `public/images/bannersMarch2019image_name`.
**No slash**.

Comment: Take a look in F12-->style and see what happend there..

Comment: yes I have checked from `inspect element` too. Path is shown correctly

Comment: Do you have any error in console? Also try to set `height/width` to div

Comment: yes I have found error in console. And there is no `slash` between folder and image name ! But why !

Comment: Are you using Voyager admin panel ?

Comment: Can you please update how are you saving image path into database ?

Comment: @AbhinavVerma...yes voyager admin panel

Comment: if your files are stored in storage folder then no need to add public in image url

Comment: @ViperTecPro...I have updated my post

Answer (score 1):

Try this **code** in your html:

```
<div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('{{asset('images/banners/March2019') }}/{{$banner[0]->banner_image}}');">
```

Using **asset** helper function to reach your actual path. I hope it would helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a laravel issue but a bootstrap issue. Have a look at [bootstrap > components > carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/)

Try this:

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="{{ url('public/images/' . $banner[0]->banner_image) }}" class="d-block">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the close of `'`

Comment: @Dimitri Mostrey....... in my carousel I have to set image as background not `img src`.

Comment: {{ ? {{ ? why two times ?

Comment: If this `$banner[0]->banner_image` contains proper path then `{{ url( $banner[0]->banner_image) }}` would be enough, i suggest save only file name to database this should only return `$banner[0]->banner_image` ...`some_filename`

Comment: I admit there was a mistake in the code, I have corrected it. In any case, it is better to make use of Laravel's integrated file system (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem). In this case it would be `Storage::url('images/' . $banner[0]->banner_image);`

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't add public in your url method, webserver root is at public, therefore your code should be:

```
<div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('images/{{ $banner[0]->banner_image }}')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot suggest/folder structure that you might be using [Voyager Admin panel](https://laravelvoyager.com/), if that is the case then you can use your image in below manner :

```
<div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('{{ Voyager::Image($banner[0]->banner_image) }}')">
```

This should help you, i would suggest please read voyager docs carefully.

Answer (score -1):

lets say this is your div tag in views file

other pages wont access it since its limited to give path, 
add / before images
eg